# Как сделать Proxy server из Ubuntu с Kubernetes?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, proxy, развертывание, kubernetes

Уделённый сервер Ubuntu с Kubernetes. Доступ из консоли по SSH.
Как превратить этот сервер в прокси-сервер? Какие утилиты для этого нужно поставить? Где найти доступный материал по такому администрированию?

Comment: Если под "прокси" имеется в виду HTTP proxy, то Squid. Если SOCKS proxy, то dante. Доступный материал — маны и документация, а также комментарии в конфигах.

Comment: Можно все таки по подробней прояснить проблему/задачу. Потому что как сформулирован вопрос сейчас, совершенно не понятно что вы хотите получить. HTTP прокси для доступа к подам кубера разворачивается самим кубиром, и управляется им же на базе nginx. Или вы хотите реализовать service-mesh для доступа к развернутым сервисам Kubernetes через проксирование TCP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно вам нужен HTTP-прокси, тогда надо установить squid.
Например по такой инструкции: https://losst.ru/ustanovka-squid-v-ubuntu-15-10
Если у вас не Ubuntu, разница только в пакетном менеджере, который установит вам пакет: вместо 'apt' в

```
sudo apt install squid
```

понадобится например yum.

Дальше нужно настроить Squid (вы же хотите чтобы он принимал только ваши запросы а не от всего интернета).

По умолчанию squid принимает запросы только с localhost.
Попробуйте для начала разрешить ему ваш IP-адрес (возможно завтра он поменяется, и менять его каждый день будет в итоге неудобно. Потом можно будет добавить авторизацию по паролю).

Узнать ваш IP-адрес, как его видит сервер, можно командой w или who.

добавьте в конфиг /etc/squid/squid.conf строчку

```
acl localnet src XX.XX.XX.XX
```

где вместо XX.XX.XX.XX  IP вашего компьютера (который показывают w или who).
Перезапустите squid.
Попробуйте подключиться.
Чуть более понятная инструкция по-английски: https://www.tecmint.com/install-squid-in-ubuntu/

В SSH есть встроенная SOCKS-прокси (тогда squid на сервере не нужен, но нужно подключаться по ssh каждый раз)
Ее можно включить в вашем SSH-клиенте.
Инструкция для PuTTY: https://www.forwardproxy.com/2018/12/using-putty-to-setup-a-quick-socks-proxy/
Инструкция для SecureCRT: https://www.vandyke.com/support/tips/socksproxy.html

Если у вас Linux или Mac OS на локальном компьютере:

```
ssh -D <local_proxy_port> <server_address>
```